# ruby/erb/cgi -- get method works, but post doesn't

Tags: ruby, post, get, cgi, erb

I am trying to write a simple eruby (erb) cgi form.  Everything works fine, if I use method="get".  For example, the following code just dumps the cgi parameters.

```
<html><body>
<% require 'cgi' %>
<% cgi = CGI.new %>
<%= cgi.keys %>
<form action="/sscms/temp.rhtml" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="Grover">    
    <input type="submit" value="save">                                        
</form>
</body></html>
```

However, if I change "get" to "post", the cgi parameters are always empty.  This seems to work with plain-old ruby cgi.  So it appears to be an eruby/cgi problem. Everything I've seen online seems to say that get and post are treated the same by ruby.  Is there something I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out.  The script I was using to get erb to work on my web host was already calling

    cgi = CGI.new

If I get rid of that line in my code, then the post method works.

In the larger scheme, this means passing the cgi instance from the rhtml file to my separate ruby code (rather than calling CGI.new directly).

Now this leaves the open question: why did it work for the get method?  My guess is that it parses the URL directly, which doesn't change if CGI.new is called.

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question with a comment. Stack overflow won't let me answer it for 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

> ["a CGI program is called with the parameters of the request passed in either in the environment (GET) or via $stdin (POST)"](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html), you can only consume $stdin once but you can read the environment as many times as you want.